# Index building quits, how to continue from there

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

In Sitecore 7, if Index building process quits (building indexes for 20million+ items for hours and hours), how to continue index rebuilding from there?

Answer (score 0):

If the lastindexupdate timestamp value was updated, you'll have no issues. Indexing should continue on the next scheduled indexing job.

Answer (score 0):

If it's that large, perhaps you could break up what you are indexing a bit and try something like this http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Index_Viewer.aspx to allow you to index specific indexes seperately and you might have more luck?